# Scrambling of letters within a text file

Tags: python, string, scramble

I am preparing a test data which must have different letters say அ-20 times 
ம-30 times , த-40 times .....( They are UTF-8 coding supported Tamil Languague letters )
this could be achieved using a print statement

```
{print ( ' ம் ' * 30 ) + ( ' த ' * 40  ) + }
```

But , I need to scramble them so that they dont appear in any particular order . I have around 230+ letters which I would be printing for 20,30,40 times . And then I need to scramble them and write them to an output file . 
Any help in this regard be helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to my friend @AswinMurugesh  who helped me with the code .

The following code did the trick .

```
import codecs
import tamil
from random import shuffle

inp_file = codecs.open("/home/sibi/Desktop/scramble.txt",encoding="utf-8")
inp_text = inp_file.read().rstrip()

tamil_letters = tamil.utf8.get_letters(inp_text)
shuffle(tamil_letters)
tamil_letters = "".join(tamil_letters).encode("utf-8")
print tamil_letters

out_file = open('outputscrambled.txt','w')
out_file.write(tamil_letters)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways you could go about this. The most efficient will be using the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

### [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> my_string = list('This is a test string.')
>>> shuffle(my_string)
>>> scrambled = ''.join(my_string)
>>> print(scrambled)
.sTtha te s rtisns gii
```

For this, you *must* create a `list` from the characters of the string, because strings are [*immutable*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-immutable).

> A new object has to be created if a different value has to be stored.

### [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> my_string = 'This is a test string.'
>>> scrambled = random.sample(my_string, len(my_string))
>>> scrambled = ''.join(scrambled)
>>> print(scrambled)
gr.s i tisstheit Tn sa
```

You don't have to create a `list` for this; because, from the `random.sample` documentation:

> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while leaving the original population unchanged.

### [The `sorted` built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random)

```
>>> from random import random
>>> my_string = 'This is a test string.'
>>> scrambled = sorted(my_string, key=lambda i: random())
>>> scrambled = ''.join(scrambled)
>>> print(scrambled)
ngi rts ithsT.staie s
```

You don't need a `list` for this either. From the `sorted` documentation:

> Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

Because a string is treated as an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) (see below) in Python, `sorted` can be used on it.

An iterable is defined as

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time.

Comment: I tried random , shuffle . While its a good option for English alphabets , it plays a different way for Tamil .Eg. assuming that கா  is present in the original text , its represented as 2 character , so shuffle will get confused with that and start printing junk if it shuffles . Tats the problem here

Comment: I would recommend the third suggestion then. The sorted builtin. @sibikanagaraj

Comment: The 3rd suggestion is the one which I am using
`# coding=utf-8

from random import random
my_string = 'அ ஆ ந் '
scrambled = sorted(my_string, key=lambda i: random())
scrambled = ''.join(scrambled)
print(scrambled)`

But the output is again junk characters

Comment: Can you give an example of these so-called junk characters? @sibikanagaraj

Comment: First I run it without # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- .
And it gives the error :
 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file stack.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Next , I add the unicode 8 
Now the output is 
������ ���

Answer (score 2):

I suggest splitting this problem into 3 parts: assemble your list of letters, shuffle the list, then write it to a file.  Note that the first line in the following code should be at the top of your python file to allow you to use utf-8 characters in the source code itself.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs  # To write UTF-8 characters to a file
import random

# Assemble data list    
letters = [u'அ', u'ம', u'த']
data = []  # This list will hold the shuffled data

for current_letter in letters:
    # Choose how many times to repeat the current letter.
    times_repeated = random.choice([20, 30, 40])
    data.extend([current_letter] * times_repeated)

# Now, shuffle the 'data' list
random.shuffle(data)

# Now write the shuffled list to a file as one continuous string
data_string = "".join(data)

with codecs.open("data.txt", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    f.write(data_string)
```

Note that if you know how many times you want each letter to show up, you could put that information into a dictionary instead of choosing randomly from `[20, 30, 40]`:

```
# The key is the letter to repeat, the value is the number of times to repeat it
letters = {u'அ': 20,
           u'ம': 30,
           u'த': 20}

for letter in letters:
    times_repeated = letters[letter]
    # ... rest of the code would look the same ...
```

Comment: In your `for` loop, it would be better to use `letters.get(letter, 0)`.

Comment: @zachgates7 

While using this code , I get the error :

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @sibikanagaraj I've updated the answer to support utf-8 characters in the source code itself, which should fix your issue. Specifically, I added an encoding line at the top and I changed the declaration of the `letters` list.

Answer (score -1):

Just use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
size = 1000
values = [' ம் ', ' த ', ' த ']
print "".join(random.choice(values) for i in xrange(size))
```